# How to get rows having uncommon values in two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table a with columns `A1`,`A2`,`A3`,`A4` and table b with columns `B1`,`B2`,`B3`,`B4`.
I want to find a records which are having different values in column `A1`,`A2` and `B1`,`B2`
Ex.

```
A1 A2 A3 A4             B1 B2 B3 B4
12 10 10 12             12 10 10 12
14 14 10 12             15 10 10 12
15 10 10 10             15 10 10 10 

IT SHOULD RETURN
14 14 10 10
```

I tried:

```
SELECT A1,A2
FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT B1,B2
FROM B;
```

However, it returned on `A1`,`A2` columns instead of all columns

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING?

Comment: -_-                       .            .        .       .        .      .

Comment: Might be I get this wrong, but - as far as I understand - you want to compare row 1 in A with row 1 in B and so on. Without an explicit sorting this is not possible. Are there more columns?

Comment: I can';t actually work out how the OP gets the result they are after. There are no rows with with values `14, 14, 10, 10`. I thought *maybe* that were `A1, A2, B1, B2` but there are no rows where `B1` has a value of `10`. Really not sure, considering that the expected result has no header.

Comment: Presumably you want it to return `14 14 10 12`, based on the data you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use left join

```
 select a.* from tableA a 
       left join tbaleB b 
       on a.A1=b.B1 and a.A2=b.B2 and a.A3=b.B3 and a.A4=b.B4
       where b.B1 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using left join

```
select * from tableA
left join tableB on A1=B1 and A2=B2 
where B1 is null and B2 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where a.a1 = b.b1 and a.a2 = b.b2
                 );
```